# WatiN - Find Form By Element

Tags: watin

I have a sample webpage:

```
<form action=blabla.php methog=post>...</form>
<form action=blabla.php methog=post>...</form>
<form action=blabla.php methog=post>...</form>
<form action=blabla.php methog=post>...</form>
<form action=blabla.php methog=post><textarea name="data"></textarea><input type="submit"></form>
```

I want to set textarea and submit last form. It's OK, I can find the text area with Find.ByName("data") syntax.

But how can I find the corresponding form for the "data" element?

I don't want to use

```
browser.Forms[index]
```

Is there any way how I can find a corresponding form to be able to make Form.Submit() ?

Comment: Do you want to find a form that contains textarea with name="data"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you get your text area (for eg in a `var textArea`) just use `Ancestor()`

```
Form myForm = textArea.Ancestor("form");
```

.Ancestor(...) resembles .Parent in ASP.NET

Comment: This answer is correct and should have been flagged as such.  Thanks Shady, exactly what I needed.